# How to show specific attribute from json file and write into another json file using Python?

Tags: python, json, github, github-api

I got a few of problems regarding to retrieving attribute from json file. I got this error message after execute the script

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

My code

```
import json

githubusers_data_path = 'githubusers.json'

githubusers_file = open(githubusers_data_path, "r")
githubusers_string = ''.join(line for line in githubusers_file)
githubusers_string = '[{}]'.format(githubusers_string)
githubusers_data = json.loads(githubusers_string)

for val in githubusers_data.values():
    print val["login"]
```

Then what I want is to rewrite the existing file (output.json) with this desirable output (must have break line).

```
{"login": "crynobone"}
{"login": "syamilmj"}
{"login": "kamal"}
{"login": "datomnurdin"}
{"login": "ejamesc"}
{"login": "kagesenshi"}
{"login": "soggie"}
{"login": "aizatto"}
{"login": "mahmudahsan"}
{"login": "erikdubbelboer"}
...
```

Original data

```
{
    "login": "datomnurdin",
    "id": 5416242,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/5416242?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/datomnurdin",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "score": 1.0
}, {
    "login": "ejamesc",
    "id": 337175,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/337175?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/ejamesc",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/ejamesc/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false,
    "score": 1.0
},...
```

Comment: Please do not edit your questions with answers given. If you found your solution, post another answer or edit the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

githubusers_data_path = 'data.txt'

githubusers_file = open(githubusers_data_path, "r")
githubusers_string = ''.join(line for line in githubusers_file)
githubusers_string = '[{}]'.format(githubusers_string)
githubusers_data = json.loads(githubusers_string)
out = open( 'output.txt', 'w' )
for val in githubusers_data:
    dict = {}
    dict['login'] = val["login"]
    out.write( json.dumps(dict) + '\n' )
out.close()
```

output:

```
{"login": "datomnurdin"}
{"login": "ejamesc"}
...
```

Comment: I upvote you because the answer is correct. But how about the write into file?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with follow code:

```
githubusers_data_path = 'githubusers.json'

githubusers_file = open(githubusers_data_path, "r")
githubusers_string = ''.join(line for line in githubusers_file)
githubusers_string = '[{}]'.format(githubusers_string)
githubusers_data = json.loads(githubusers_string)

for val in githubusers_data:
    print '{"%s": "%s"}' % ("login", val["login"])
```

Comment: I upvote you because the answer is correct. But how about the write into file?

Answer (score 1):

```
logins = "\n".join(map(lambda u: '{"login": "%s"}' % u['login'], githubusers_data))
open("logins.txt", "w").write(logins)
```